# How can I get the full canonical request in php

Tags: php, http, request

I am just wondering how to get the full canonical request to a php file, I just want to echo it back as text or html.

for example: a get request to file.php outputs the following

output:

```
GET http://path/to/this/file.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: example
... other parameters
```

edit: I would like the complete string in tact

Comment: Try look for `$_SERVER` ??

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER)` will show all the information about the request that you can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to get the original request string, as far as I know. However, all the information that comes from the request header is put into the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) associative array. Every header field `Xxx-Yyy` corresponds to `$_SERVER['HTTP_XXX_YYY']` -- the letters in the header name are converted to uppercase, and hyphens are replaced with underscores. So you can do:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . ' ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . ' ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] "\n";
foreach ($_SERVER AS $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') {
        echo str_replace('_', '-', substr($key, 5)) . ': ' . $value . "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getallheaders()` method to get an array of the request headers. From here you can loop thru them and output them as you require.

```
foreach(getallheaders() as $k => $v) {
  echo $k . ': ' . $v . PHP_EOL;  
}
```

More details can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php